# Python dataframe : Add a column that increments when another column changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Values' : [False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
})
df
```

```
    Values
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   False
4   False
5   True
6   True
7   False
8   False
9   True
```

I would like to add another column named 'count' which increment by one whenever a True detects in 'Values' column

My expected output is as follows

```
    Values  Count
0   False   0
1   False   0
2   True    1
3   False   1
4   False   1
5   True    2
6   True    3
7   False   3
8   False   3
9   True    4
```

Now I am doing as follows

```
counter = [0]
def handleOneRow(row):
    if row['Values'] == True:
        counter[0] = counter[0] + 1
    return counter[0]
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda x : handleOneRow(x), axis=1)
```

Is there any other simple way in dataframe ?

Comment: `df['Count'] = df['Values'].cumsum()`

Comment: Thanks, I searched a lot, but couldn't find it. Awesome...